# The number of positive integral solutions of $abc =$ $30$ is

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations

> The number of positive integral solutions of $abc =$ $30$ is

**My attempt**

Factors of $30$ are $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 2$.

Therefore $a$ will have **three** choices, similarly $b$ & $c$ will have $2$ choices & $1$ choice.

So,it's answer must be $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$

But answer in my textbook is given is $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$.
.It states that"$2$ can be assigned to either $a$ or $b$ or $c$".  Similarly, each of $3$ and $5$ can be assigned in $3$ ways.  Thus, the number of solutions is $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$

According to me, if $a$ is already assigned to $2$ than how can other letters ($b$ or $c$) have same value as that of $a$.

Please explain me where am I wrong?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that if $3$ is assigned to $c$, then $2$ and $5$ cannot be assigned to $c$.  However, this is not the case.  A valid factorization of $30$ in the positive integers is $30 = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 15$, where $a = 1$, $b = 2$, and $c = 15 = 3 \cdot 5$.

Comment: The factors of $30$ are $1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me

Comment: You are assuming $a,b,c$ must be the prime factors.  You are forget they one or two of the terms can be $1$ and one of the other terms can be a composite.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sir what's the code to add some text in blue color boxes like I used code orange box

Comment: @ fleablood  thanks sir I got my mistake

Comment: @fleablood  sir what's the code to add some text in blue color boxes like I used code orange box

Comment: If you are in math mode, you can write 30 = 2 \cdot \color{blue}{3} \cdot \color{red}{5} to produce $30 = 2 \cdot \color{blue}{3} \cdot \color{red}{5}$.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: All of the answers, including the one given in the textbook, assume that different orders of the same factors are distinct solutions to the problem, i.e. $1\cdot 1\cdot 30$, $1\cdot 30\cdot 1$, and $30\cdot 1\cdot 1$ are different solutions. If such is not allowed, there only five distinct solutions: $1\cdot 1\cdot 30$, $1\cdot 2\cdot 15$, $1\cdot 3\cdot 10$, $1\cdot 5\cdot 6$, and $2\cdot 3\cdot 5$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$abc=30$

First write $30$ as the prime factors

$30=2\times3\times5$

$a=2^{x_1}\times3^{y_2}\times5^{z_3}$

$b=2^{x_2}\times3^{y_2}\times5^{z_2}$

$c=2^{x_3}\times3^{y_3}\times5^{z_3}$

$$abc=30$$
$$2^{{x_1}+{y_1}+{z_1}+{x_2}+{y_2}+{z_2}+{x_3}+{y_3}+{z_3}}=30$$note that $$x_1+x_2+x_3=1...(1)$$$$y_1+y_2+y_3=1....(2)$$$$z_1+z_2+z_3=1.....(3)$$
Notice that $(1),(2),(3)$ have only $3$ solutions each

So, the total number of solutions are $3\times3\times3=27$

Comment: thanks,sir  for helping me

Answer (score 2):

The texbook is right.

Start with $1\cdot1\cdot1$ and assign $2$, say to $b$ and get $1\cdot2\cdot1$.

Now assign $3$, say to $a$ and get $3\cdot2\cdot1$.

Then assign $5$ to $a$ again, giving $15\cdot2\cdot1$.

On every stage, you have three choices.

Comment: thanks sir for helping me

Answer (score -1):

Hint: (Slightly different point of view than the book; but will lead to same answer).

There are many ways to write $30$ as a product of three factors, such as $1\cdot 1\cdot 30$ or $1\cdot 5\cdot 6$.

I think you have neglected some of these cases.

Comment: This is a non-answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Looking at OP's work it looked to me like they thought that the three factors had to be 2, 3, 5 in some order.  I was trying to point out that there are other possibilities.  But thanks for the feedback anyway!

Comment: Ok, but better leave this as a comment.

Comment: Seeing as the question was where he was wrong this is a legitimate answer.  (Although I'd classify this type of question as one where a comment would serve to answer and post should be used for going beyond the answer)